# testing that a user can edit profile

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5.8

Simple enough situation, a user can edit their own profile. Run it through a browser test, works like a charm. Make a test for it... well now we have something interesting. I posted this over on the [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-that-a-user-can-edit-profile#) site, but I figure more exposure is always good.

```
/** @test */
    function auth_user_can_edit_own_profile()
    {
        $user = factory('App\User')->create();
        $user->setProfile();  //this just makes an empty profile so a 1-1 relation exists
        $this->actingAs($user);
        $response = $this->post('profile/'.$user->id.'/update',[
            'quote'=>'Hello World',
        ]);
        $response->assertSee('Hello World');
    }
```

I get a failure. what displays on the screen is a redirect to the main page.  O.o   Nothing in my code should make that happen.

I believe it has something to do with my form request's authorize() method. However, I fail to see how.  I have tried using $this->withoutExceptionHandling() in my test with no change.

```
storeProfile form request:

public function authorize()
    {
        $profile = $this->route('profile');
        if ($this->user()->can('edit profile') || $this->user()->id == $profile->user_id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


Profile Controller update:

public function update(storeProfile $request, Profile $profile)
    {
        $profile->update($request->except('name'));
        $profile->save();

        if($profile->user->name != $request->input('name'))
        {
            $profile->user()->update(['name' => $request->input('name')]);
            //TODO event to track name changes
        }

        return redirect()->action('ProfileController@show',['id' => $profile->user_id]);
    }
```

Any insights to this would be really helpful, but I truly don't understand what is happening. Thank you all for taking the time to read and help!

Things I have tried:

- Set authroize to return true. - no change
- $this->flushSession(); - no change
- $this->withoutExceptionHandling() - nochange

Comment: In my opinion, you are misusing the browser test in this case. You should fill the update form in your test method and submit the form. Performing a post request from within the test method behaves differently.

Comment: I have little knowledge, so I'm curious, how does the test behave differently? All I'm doing is skipping the actual form filling out stage and just posting data to the same endpoint the form has. I have other tests that I do the same thing with and they handle just as expected. I'm all for rewriting the test, but the way it's written, it should work.

Comment: In normal tests, when you use `$this->post($url)`, a request will be simulated in the same thread as the test runs. In browser tests, you actually have at least 3 threads. One for the tests, one for the browser (chromium driver) and at least one for the application itself (normal webserver). In other words, a normal browser test will be managed from the test thread, but executed from the browser thread towards the webserver. If you execute a request within the test, you are leaving out the other two threads. -- Btw., just to make sure, with _browser test_ you mean _Dusk test_, right?

Comment: Also, what's different between a Dusk test and a normal unit test is the way you authenticate. When you use `$this->longAs($user)` in a Dusk test, it will set a session for the chrome browser. In a normal test, using `$this->actingAs($user)` will simply set this user in the authentication guard, as the request is performed in the same thread.

Comment: No I'm not using Dusk. I just logged into the site and tested that way. I haven't installed Dusk yet to test the front end. I wanted to get the back end going first.

Comment: well that was interesting. I had to set a get request to the profile page first.. then I could request the post for the test. Now it passes. It's interesting that I couldn't post straight after the user "logged in". Not that I'm complaining, that's a great feature to have. Still I think it's solved now.

Comment: Do you use a `csrf_token()` by chance?

Comment: csrf is disabled during tests.